# Display legend for every series with Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, legend, dygraphs

I am rendering multiple independent time series with Dygraphs as described here:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/independent-series.html

The graph is rendered correctly:

[image: graph]

However I want the legend to display the value for each and every series. For now only the value of the point closest to the cursor is displayed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this.

To dygraphs, a selection always has a specific x-value. There's no notion of a set of points with different x-values that are all selected. That being said, you could roll your own legend behavior using highlightCallback and unhighlightCallback. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121893/two-dygraphs-with-synchronized-crosshair/23145299?noredirect=1#comment35417777_23145299) for an example of someone who did that.